# Why is the solution of dy/dx = y/x, y = Cx and not y = C|x|?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Since the derivative of |x| is |x|/x, does it follow that y = |x| can be differentiated to give dy/dx = |x|/x = y/x meaning that the solution of this ODE is y = C|x| rather than the standard y = Cx which one would get by the separation of variables?

This meant that I got stuck with the following question as I do not know whether it is A or D. Thank you in advance!
[MC question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSGAJ.png)

Comment: $|x|$ is not differentiable $\forall x\in R$

Comment: OK what but what if we exclude x = 0? The solutions of y = Cx and y = C|x| to the ODE still look very different! Thank you!

Comment: If you exclude $0$ from the domain, then the function $F(x)=17x$ for $x>0$ and $F(x)=-\pi x$ for $x<0$ works too.  Nothing special about $17, -\pi$, of course.

Comment: @dc999 if you exclude $x=0$, the function with $x<0$ and with $x>0$ will have no relation. That is, for instance $y=x$ for $x<0$ and $y=2x$ for $x>0$ will also be a solution.

Comment: Thanks everyone. So does that mean the answer is D and not A?

Answer (score 1):

Exactly, when you exclude $x=0$, function $y=c|x|$ falls into $y=cx$ categories.

Comment: Thank you! May I ask why this is? To me the graph of y = c|x| and y = cx looks very different for any given number c, even when x = 0 is excluded. Or are we only discussing in the sense of finding the solution to this ODE?

Comment: When you exclude x=0, y=c|x| is y=cx (when x>0) and y= -cx(when x<0). you can always let c'=-c as there is no constraint for c. So both pieces can be written in the form of y = cx.